# Problema al resetear JPanel y JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo el siguiente código java:

```
miCalendarioGestor = new MiCalendarioGestor(profiles.obtainPerfil(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            frame.getContentPane().add(miCalendarioGestor);
            frame.add(miCalendarioGestor);
            frame.repaint();
```

Lo que intento es resetear miCalendarioGestor a su momento inicial, pero esto no ocurre. Alguien tiene alguna idea? Gracias

Comment: revisa repack para el jframe.....debes empaquetar todo nuevamente y ademas setVisible(true).....!!! Si este contentPane solo tiene un elemento cada vez que agregues otro tendras 2 de ellos. Debes limpiarlo primero

Comment: He probado multitud de formas y con el ser visible también, pero no funcionaba correctamente.

Comment: Probaré lo del repaso a ver si funciona. Muchas gracias por responder!!

Comment: Intento eliminarlo y luego hacerlo visible, pero sigue sin crearse uno nuevo